# Which Swing control should I use to render graphics with?

Tags: java, graphics, swing

I'm using the Swing UI toolkit in Java, and I want to use the `Graphics` class to draw images and grids in a control. Which is the most appropriate control for this?

Answer (score 3):

A cursory [bit of searching with Google](https://www.google.com/#q=Java+swing+graphics+control) suggests that you probably want to use [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) for this, although it's possible you could make use of any control since it looks like the technique you'll want to use is to [subclass the control and override a method](http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/java/swing/graphics.html) (the `paintComponent` method, specifically), which will give you a `Graphics` instance you can use for rendering.

JPanel appears to be a very basic empty control and so is probably the ideal choice for this.